# How to embed Javascript in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a CSS file, which contain the style information of my web. 
Some height & width is based on the screen size, so I can calculate the size using 
the Javascript, can I embedded the javascript in the CSS file to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In IE, and only IE, you can use CSS expressions:

```
width: expression(blah + "px");
```

Then `width` becomes whatever's inside the brackets.

This only works in IE, though - so **don't use it**. Use a JS function to assign the elements the style with `element.style.width` or similar.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('header').style.width = (100 * 2) + 'px';
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the example use `.STYLE.width` as well?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I'm not actually sure... I'll just check.

Comment: Using expressions are so bad that they took it out of IE8

Comment: @bobince: Thanks.      @epascarello: They did? Thank God. :)

Comment: Or with jQuery: `$("#header").css("width", 100 * 2)`

Comment: @cdmckay: Thanks for the obligatory JQuery mention! :D

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so, but you can do the opposite, i.e. make the javascript create an inline css on the fly.